# Verifying windows azure account with phone number

Tags: windows, azure

I'm trying to verify my windows azure account(free trial version) from turkey, but I can't find my country at the list.When I typed my number,a notification appears which is about the phone number is incorrect form but a text message was sent by anyway.But I don't recieve any text message.
How can I verify my account?

Answer (score 1):

Contact your local Microsoft branch. The SMS verification is not working from certain countries and it's not clear from the web UI. However, they can verify you by phone.

The same problem holds for the Czech Republic for example.